# Previous and Next links not populating, have I missed something?

Tags: theme-development, loop

I'm working on a very simple theme. I have tried adding next and previous links and cannot get them to work.

After trying a few different things, I ended up with this `index.php` (mostly based on answers on SO).

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<!-- html stuff --> 
    <?php 
    if ( have_posts() ) { 
       while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
           // ... post layout stuff
       endwhile;
    } 
    ?>
<!-- Other html bits -->
<?php           
   $prev_link = get_previous_posts_link(__('&laquo; Older Entries'));
   $next_link = get_next_posts_link(__('Newer Entries &raquo;'));
   if ($prev_link || $next_link) {
       echo '<nav><ul class="pager">';
       if ($prev_link){
           echo '<li>'.$prev_link .'</li>';
       }
       if ($next_link){
           echo '<li>'.$next_link .'</li>';
       }
       echo '</ul></nav>';
   }
?>
<!-- html stuff --> 
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

There are two blog posts on the development install I am working with. But neither of them display with the navigational links.

Comment: Are they not appearing when you view the individual posts? Or when visiting the blog?

Comment: Not on individual posts, archives, anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by the default link labels, "Older Entries" and "Newer Entries", `get_next_posts_link()` and `get_next_posts_link()` are for outputting links between pages of posts. If you only have 2 posts, and your posts per page setting is set to anything higher than 1, then you're not going to have more than one page of any archive or your blog, so the links won't appear.

If you want links between single posts, then the correct functions are [`get_next_post_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_next_post_link/) and [`get_previous_post_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_previous_post_link/). Those functions *do* need to be in the loop.

While it's technically possible to use `index.php` for single posts and archives/the blog, you can avoid some confusion by starting with at least `index.php` for your lists of posts, and `singular.php` for single posts and pages. Use `get_next_posts_link()` and `get_next_posts_link()` for links between pages in `index.php`, outside the loop, but use `get_next_post_link()` and `get_previous_post_link()` for links between single posts in `singular.php`, inside the loop.

Comment: Ah, I see where I went wrong now.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code block with all the prev/next links code inside the loop.

The `get_previous_posts_link()` function relies on the current post ID, and outside of the loop that post ID is not available.

Comment: I thought that too. It did not make any difference.